Как в apscheduler можно отловить, прошла ли дата выполнения функции?
Есть тг бот, в котором пользователь вводит дату и время(время и дату меньше текущей ввести нельзя). По логике, бот должен отправить напоминание за два часа до введенной даты. Запуск функции по таймеру я реализовал при помощи APScheduler. Все работает хорошо, когда пользователь выбирает дату > 2ч(например, 22.11.2024 22:07 - бот отправит напоминание 22.11.2024 в 20:07), но когда до события меньше двух часов(например, 22.11.2024 18:10 (сейчас 18:09)) - ничего не происходит. Вопрос следующий - могу ли я как нибудь отлавливать это при помощи APScheduler и запускать функцию сразу? Пока что в голову приходит только один вариант - при помощи datetime сравнивать дату и если до события меньше двух часов, то запускать функцию сразу; иначе - запускать функцию по таймеру при помощи APScheduler.
